# Prove that $\left\{\frac{a}{2^b}: a \in\mathbb{Z}, b \in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}\right\}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: fractions, real-numbers

What am I looking for exactly?

The hint I was given: show that we can find such a fraction between any two given real numbers.